# ios8 web view open external links in safari except one

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari

I have a UIWebview that loads some pages from my server.
I wanted to open external links in Safari and used this code:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {

if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}
```

Worked perfectly.

Now from my pages showed in the web view I want to let user make a payment with paypal.
The paypal page opens in the web view but then when the user tap the button to login with his paypal account the link is opened in Safari and he receives a warning from paypal about session expired (of course).
Before adding the code above paypal pages were shown correctly in the web view, the user could complete the payment and then he was redirected to my pages to store the transaction in my database.

So, how can I open all external links in Safari except paypal pages?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the URL string from the `NSURLRequest`, then filter based on that:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    NSString *pageToVisit = inRequest.URL.absoluteString;

    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked && [pageToVisit rangeOfString:@"paypal.com"].location == NSNotFound ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I'm not familiar with PayPal's URL structure, so I'm just naively assuming that a URL that contains "paypal.com" is a PayPal link that you want to open in your web view. Tune as necessary.

Comment: Just perfect! Thank you very much! Just for everyone else who needs this, you missed "@" before the string: rangeOfString:@"paypal.com"